# Spring JPA custom repository different packages

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, repository, spring-data-jpa

I'm developing a spring boot application and i'm running into an issue here. I want to have separate packages for my RepositoryImpl, RepositoryCustom and Repository classes but when i separate the packages im getting this error:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property customMethod found for type Demo!

It only works when i put my RepositoryImpl, RepositoryCustom and Repository classes into the same package. I've tried `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.demo.persist")` but still not working.

Is there a way i can achieve this?

Here's my code:

[image: Project packages]

DemoApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.demo.persist")
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

DemoController.java

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @Autowired
    DemoService demoService;

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String getUnidades() {
        demoService.customMethod();
        return "test";
    }

}
```

DemoRepositoryCustom.java

```
public interface DemoRepositoryCustom {

    void customMethod();

}
```

DemoRepositoryImpl.java

```
public class DemoRepositoryImpl implements DemoRepositoryCustom {

    @Override
    public void customMethod() {
        // do something
    }

}
```

DemoRepositoryCustom.java

```
public interface DemoRepository extends JpaRepository<Demo, Long>, DemoRepositoryCustom {

}
```

Demo.java

```
@Entity
public class Demo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "bigint")
    private int id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "name", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(60)", length = 60, unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    // ...
```

DemoService.java

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class DemoService {

    @Autowired
    DemoRepository demoRepository;

    public void customMethod() {
        demoRepository.customMethod();
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autodetection of custom implementations work only in packages below the one declaring the Repository.

But you can make your implementation a bean with the name matching the required class name.
That would be `demoRepositoryImpl` in your case.

[See the documentation for details](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_manual_wiring).

Answer (score 1):

Actually your package hierarchy is not in right order.

Make it like this  :

```
com.example.demo.repository
com.example.demo.repository.custom
com.example.demo.repository.custom.impl
```

And it will work.